# Hide bootstrap modal within ajax 'success' callback depending on some condition while uploading a file using Formdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have been looking around to find a solution for a while now, but could not find what I am looking for.

I am trying to upload an image file using ajax using **Formdata**, the file selector(*input type file*) is inside a bootstrap modal. Now inside **success** call back, I want to close the modal depending on the response I get from the server.

Right now I am using `$("#add-slide-modal").modal('hide');` **but it is not working**.

I am looking for the reason why it is not working, there is something mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596223/how-to-restructure-the-code-in-order-to-make-bootstraps-modal-methods-asynchron) post but I could not understand it completely and I tried to use the solution in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596223/how-to-restructure-the-code-in-order-to-make-bootstraps-modal-methods-asynchron) post and it works but I want to decide either to close the modal or not on the basis of server's response.

Here is my code:

```js
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var valid = $("#add-slide-form").validationEngine('validate');
    if(valid) {
        var targeted_modal = $("#add-slide-modal");
        var parent = targeted_modal.find('.modal-body');

        // Update button text.
        uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Saving...';
        uploadButton.disabled = true;

        var request_url = ""; var add_request_flag = false;
        var formData = get_formData();
        if(targeted_modal.find("#add_or_update").val() == 'update') {
            //update existing slide
            request_url = ADMIN_BASE + "update-slide";
            formData.append('slide_id', targeted_modal.find('#slide_id').val());
        } else {
            //add new slide
            request_url = ADMIN_BASE + "add-slide";
            add_request_flag = true;
        }
        if(formData && request_url.length) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: request_url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        show_ajax_response(response, parent);
                        if(response.status == 1) {
                            uploadButton.innerHTML = "Saved";
                            if(add_request_flag) {
                                clear_modal_fields(targeted_modal);
                            } else {
                                update_client_side(response.slide);
                            }
                            uploadButton.disabled = false;

                        } else {
                            uploadButton.innerHTML = "Save";
                            uploadButton.disabled = false;
                        }
                        targeted_modal.modal('hide');
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your success function firing for sure? Does your breakpoint get hit? Does calling `$("#add-slide-modal").modal('hide');` work outside of your success function, just by calling it directly in the console?

Comment: yes `$("#add-slide-modal").modal('hide');` is firing and yes it is working outside success function.

Comment: If you're sure your success function is firing, maybe the event is just happening out of order with something else. try wrapping your modal hide call in a setTimeout, `setTimeout(function () { targeted_modal.modal('hide'); })`

Comment: already tried that as well, but no luck

Comment: I made a simplified version of your problem in a codepen http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/qdyOeK?editors=101 seems to be working okay for me, hopefully this can help

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I was `targeted_modal.removeData('bs.modal');` inside `clear_modal_fields()` function, which is creating some trouble. I just commented it and everything worked fine.